# How to set/change IP for intel(R) 82579LM gigabit adapter?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, network-adapter, static-ip

I want to set static IP to my wireless network adapter, but I get this error:

[[image]]

so I want to change IP address of this adapter.

I should set my wireless IP to 192.168.1.157.

Also I restart my laptop, but still I get this error.

More info:
laptop = lenoveo T420
Win = 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Disable your ethernet adapter
2. Set your static IP on the wireless adapter
3. Before enabling the ethernet adapter, go to it's properties, check if it's set to manual or automatic.
4. If it is set to manual, then put it on automatic, or change your address. Confirm the dialog.
5. Enable the adapter. If it shows an error, then diagnose and fix the ethernet adapter. (alternatively you can try to ipconfig /release and /renew the ethernet adapter)

I hope this helps.

Comment: I set manual ip to my ethernet adapter, but when I want to change wireless adapter ip my internet disconnected and now I get this [error](http://tinypic.com/r/3020zmx/8) when try to set static ip to it.

Comment: @The Image confirmation(it's not an error, more of a warning): As long as you know what you're doing, you can click 'Yes'.

As for the configuration: You can't have the same address on both adapters at the same time. If you're going to change one, make sure the other one doesn't have the same address on it.
For example, if you want to change A from 1 to 2, and B from 2 to 1, then you must first do A = 0(instead of 2), then B = 1(so that B's address doesn't conflict with A), and finally A = 2.

Answer (score 0):

This happens sometimes when the computer thinks your network adapter is a new adapter. In the case of your wireless adapter, is it USB or internal?

If you don't have another adapter with this IP already assigned to it, just click yes and let it be assigned you wanted it to be.

Edit:

Just to add, when I say it thinks you have more than one even though you don't, I'm referring to when for some reason, your computer "unsees" you network device and then rediscovers it as a new device with the same name but a number appended to it like "network device" and then "network device (2)"

This is very common with USB wireless devices and when you unplug it and plug it into a new USB port.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your Ethernet Adapter has been assigned that IP by DHCP & it has a lease duration. You should release that IP address first before assigning it to another network Adapter

1: Open Command Prompt as an Administrator & run the command below

```
ipconfig /release
```

2: Disable the Ethernet adapter, so that DHCP doesn't assign it back

3: Set Static IP address on your Wireless Card now

4: Enable Ethernet Adapter after this & it should be assigned a new IP by DHCP as other one is already in use

Comment: Not sure that's right. If you are getting an ip address dynamically and then assign it a static ip of the same value, it doesn't do this.

Comment: @Geruta, if you have two network cards on your computer then try assign your ethernet adapters ip address statically to your wireless card following my instructions and see if it works or not

Comment: So, his title says assign static ip to his gigabit adapter but then in the writing he puts assign static to wireless. Which is it?

Comment: Yeah, that is little confusing statement but he clearly says that he is trying to set static ip address on wireless card. I think he is said so because he was not able to set static ip because of it, and just thought of changing it so that it won't conflict again. just guessing though

Comment: I may have misread this. If I did and he is trying to assign a static ip to his wireless when his physical Ethernet adapter is dynamically assigned the same address, then absolutely yes that's the problem lol